# Different way of program flow depending on variable ($_POST["command"]) - Why does my code not work?

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to show differenet content depending on the variable passed to the script

```
$command = $_POST["command"];

if ($command == "Edit") {

?>

CONTENT 1

<?
} elseif ($command == "Delete") {
?>

CONTENT 2

<?php
} else
?>

CONTENT 3

<?php
}
?>
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Please explain what errors you get.

Comment: You should enable error_reporting and display_errors, it would have struck you at once

Comment: @DamienPirsy how do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must read your code several times carefully to check any obvious errors.

In this case, you didn't write `{` after `else`. :(

`} else` -> `} else {`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use some brackets.  New code:

```
$command = $_POST["command"];

if ($command == "Edit") {

?>

CONTENT 1

<?php
} elseif ($command == "Delete") {
?>

CONTENT 2

<?php
} else {
?>

CONTENT 3

<?php
}
?>
```